# Execute @Handler method in multi-thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, apache-camel

Need to execute @Handler(import org.apache.camel.Handler) method in multi-threading environment. below is my current code and camelroute.xml file. Any Idea or suggestion would be appreciable.

```
@Component("messagehandler")
public class HandleMessages {   
    @Handler
    public void handle(String body, Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
      // do some business operation
    }
    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <route id="IncomingRoute">
         <from uri="someSourceURL" />       
        <to uri="bean:messagehandler" />
        <log message="Message Body - ${body}" />
    </route>

</routes>
```

Comment: What's the current problem you are facing?

Comment: not the problem but unaware of how to implement multithreading in this case so that @Handler method will run in multiple threads for parallel processing of messages from even hub

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, thread safety **is all about execution** – that's all. A given method / routine / piece of code is thread-safe if it guarantees the manipulation of shared data (data structures, etc.) *safely* in a way that multiple threads don't *corrupt* that data.

So it really depends on how you structure the execution of a given workflow; and that's the same for any other piece of code you can think of.

Since you are using Apache Camel, take a look at their [threading model](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/threading-model.html). If I remember correctly, you would have to define your routes / workflows in such a way they run concurrently by using `parallelProcessing` (CC EIP), a custom thread pool, or using staged event-driven architecture (SEDA); at that point you would need to take care about what you do in the handlers (or any other "processor(s)" that handle shared data), otherwise you should be OK.

Another thing you need to think about is how Camel uses its routing engine to route messages synchronously or asynchronously; be aware that synchronicity and MEP affects the threading model.